# Can't see why it does not work

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a few tables and I can't manage to get my keys to work properly.

```
Create table FAQ (
 id int(10) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 question text,
 answer text
);
Create table templates (
 id int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name varchar(80),
 value varchar(30),
 sql_db text,
 sql_table text,
 Primary Key(id,name,value)
);
Create table clientes(
 id int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
 nome varchar(80),
 email varchar(30),
 website varchar(80),
 template_name varchar(80),
 template_value varchar(30),
 modo varchar(10),
 data datetime,
 Primary Key (id),
 FOREIGN KEY (template_name) REFERENCES templates(name),
 FOREIGN KEY (template_value) REFERENCES templates(value)
);
```

I just want to make simple relations between those 2 tables.

Comment: It is kind of weird to build a PK on id, name, and value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate answer to your question is that a foreign key needs to reference *all* columns a unique key.  That also requires a unique index on the two columns, so it should look like:

```
Create table FAQ (
  id int(10) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  question text,
  answer text
);

Create table templates (
  id int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(80),
  value varchar(30),
  sql_db text,
  sql_table text,
  Primary Key(id),
  Unique (name, value)
);

Create table clientes (
  id int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nome varchar(80),
  email varchar(30),
  website varchar(80),
  template_name varchar(80),
  template_value varchar(30),
  modo varchar(10),
  data datetime,
  Primary Key (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (template_name, template_value) REFERENCES templates(name, value)
);
```

However, it is better to use the primary key (the auto-incremented id).  Then you look up the name and value using `join`:

```
Create table clientes (
  id int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nome varchar(80),
  email varchar(30),
  website varchar(80),
  template_id int,
  modo varchar(10),
  data datetime,
  Primary Key (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (template_id) REFERENCES templates(id)
);
```